# RDP copy paste working unidirectionally

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have a windows 10 PC (as the client) through which I RDP to Windows Server 2012 R2. I can copy paste files from the Server to the client, but cannot do so from the client to the Server.

Is there something that I am missing to enable this ?
(As a side note, on some other thread, I read enabling and disabling `rdpclip.exe`, should help, but that does not work. I cannot see `rdpclip.exe` listed in the processes tab in task manager).

Additionally, there are other users who have the same rights as me, are successfully able to perform copy paste operation bidirectionally.

Comment: I face same issue with my Win 8.1 machine. However, this occurs only when i do not restart my machine for 2~3 weeks . After restarting my machine, it works fine again.